# What are some quick methods for calculating hyperbolic equations?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given that the hyperbola passes through three of the four points (m1, m2, m3, m4), find the equation for the hyperbola

These four points are like this

```
m1 = {4, Sqrt[2]/3}; m2 = {3, Sqrt[
  2]}; m3 = {-2, -Sqrt[3]/3}; m4 = {2, Sqrt[3]/3};
```

Is there a fast way to automatically remove points that are not on a hyperbola and use the other three points to calculate the hyperbolic equation. How to design a program?

The method I tried myself was manually calculated using the symmetry of the hyperbola, and the code is as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
m1 = {4, Sqrt[2]/3}; m2 = {3, Sqrt[
  2]}; m3 = {-2, -Sqrt[3]/3}; m4 = {2, Sqrt[3]/3};
sol1 = First@
  Solve[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1 /. Thread[{x, y} -> m2], 
    x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1 /. Thread[{x, y} -> m3], 
    x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1 /. Thread[{x, y} -> m4], {a, b} > 0}, {a, 
    b}, Reals]
x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1 /. sol1
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the hyperbola is centered at a particular point, and that its asymptotes are oriented in a particular way?  If not, you can draw a conic section of *some* kind through any five points, and so I suspect you can draw an infinite number of hyperbolas through any four points.

Comment: The center of the hyperbola is the coordinate origin {0,0}

Comment: In that case, note that any hyperbola centered at (0,0) will automatically pass through `m3` and `m4`, since $m_3 = - m_4$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that three points match, create all possible data subsets

```
mi = {{4, Sqrt[2]/3}, {3, Sqrt[2]}, {-2, -(1/Sqrt[3])}, {2, 1/Sqrt[3]}};
dmi = Subsets[mi, {3} ]
```

Fit all and select the best fit

```
fits=(Table[NMinimize[# . # &[Map[#[[1]]^2/a^2 - #[[2]]^2/b^2 - 1 &, dmi[[k]]]], {a, b}], {k, 1,Length[dmi]}] )
(*{
{0.617564, {a -> 3.4889, b -> 33280.6}}, 
{0.617564, {a -> 3.4889,b ->33280.6}},
{1., {a -> 3.4641,b -> 12744.4}}, 
{9.42935*10^-31, {a -> 1.73205, b -> 1.}}
}*)

opt=MinimalBy[fits, #[[2, 1]] &][[1]]
(*{{4, {9.42935*10^-31, {a -> 1.73205, b -> 1.}}}}*)

Show[{ContourPlot[ Evaluate[1 == x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 /. opt[[2, 2]]], {x, -2,  4}, {y, -1, 2}], ListPlot[mi, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As a hyperbola is defined by 3 points, your question is not clear.

E.g. given your 3 first points:

```
m1 = {4, Sqrt[2]/3}; m2 = {3, Sqrt[ 2]}; m3 = {-2, -Sqrt[3]/3};

eq = (y - m1[[2]])/(x - m1[[1]]) (x - m2[[1]])/(y - 
      m2[[2]]) == (m3[[2]] - m1[[2]])/(m3[[1]] - m1[[1]]) (m3[[1]] - 
      m2[[1]])/(m3[[2]] - m2[[2]])
f[x_] = y /. Solve[eq, y][[1]]
```

Now we can plot the hyperbola:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -6, 6}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{m1, m2, m3}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-6, 6}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]